# SQL Server : AFTER INSERT trigger and INSERT INTO

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I want to create a trigger that will fill up my sales history base after firing in the `ORDER` table.

I am creating a specific order in regular data base and after that this order automatically goes to `sales_history` database.

Below part works properly.

When I create a new order in regular database my sales_history database is growing with new `ID_ORDERS`, hooray! :)

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[InsertTrig]
ON [dbo].[ORDER]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM inserted i
               WHERE i.ID_TYPE = 1)   -- specific order type
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO id.dbo.sales_history (id_order)
            SELECT i.ID_ORDER FROM inserted i
    END
```

The problem arises when I want join another table. The trigger stops working

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[InsertTrig]
ON [dbo].[ORDER]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM inserted i
               WHERE i.ID_TYPE = 1)   -- specific order type
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO id.dbo.sales_history (id_order, id_item)
            SELECT
                inserted.ID_ORDER, ORDER_DETAILS.ID_ITEM
            FROM
                inserted
            INNER JOIN
                ORDER_DETAILS ON ORDER_DETAILS.ID_ORDER = inserted.ID_ORDER
    END
```

I also tried this way, and still nothing :(

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[InsertTrig]
ON [dbo].[ORDER]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM inserted i
               WHERE i.ID_TYPE = 1)   -- specific order type
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @xyz AS numeric(18, 0)

        SET @xyz = (SELECT inserted.ID_ORDER FROM inserted)

        INSERT INTO id.dbo.sales_history (id_order, id_item)
            SELECT
                ORDER.ID_ORDER, ORDER_DETAILS.ID_ITEM
            FROM
                ORDER
            INNER JOIN
                ORDER_DETAILS ON ORDER_DETAILS.ID_ORDER = ORDER.ID_ORDER
            WHERE
                ORDER.ID_ORDER = @xyz
    END
```

I want to create a trigger that will automatically fill up my sales history base after firing in ORDER table.

Comment: [The trigger stops working](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) What does this mean? Unexpected results? Error? You don't need `exists` simply insert with a `where` clause.

Comment: Your 3rd attempt assumes an `INSERT` always contains 1 row; this isn't true.

Comment: The trigger stops working - base sales_history just stop increasing when i create new orders

Comment: What do you mean by it "stops increasing"? As in you have column that is meant to increment and isn't? Is it defined as an `IDENTITY` or does it use a `SEQUENCE`?

Comment: stop increasing mean - Newly created rows in the ORDER table are not copied to the table Sales_history. Only  In the first variant of my code, this happens. I want copy only records from two columns from ORDER table.

Comment: Using: Activity Monitor check if there is blocked con.

Comment: Like https://samirbehara.com/2017/08/24/identify-sql-blocking-issues-using-activity-monitor/

Comment: Triggers https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/sqlserver/triggers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger is on the `Order` table, meaning SQL Server fires it after you insert records into the `Order` table. At which point, the relevant records in the `Order_Details` table couldn't have been inserted yet, because they have a foreign key to the `Order` table.
This is why an inner join between your `inserted` table and the `Order_details` table returns 0 rows.

If you want your `sales_history` from the `order_details` table, you have to populate it after you insert the records to the `order_details` table.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[OrderDetails_AfterInsert]
ON [dbo].[ORDER_DETAILS]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
    INSERT INTO id.dbo.sales_history (id_order, id_item)
    SELECT
        inserted.ID_ORDER, inserted.ID_ITEM
    FROM
        inserted
    INNER JOIN
        [ORDER] ON [ORDER].ID_ORDER = inserted.ID_ORDER
    WHERE [ORDER].ID_TYPE = 1  -- specific order type
```

As a side note: `InsertTrig` is bad name. Note the name of the trigger in my answer - it tells you exactly what this trigger is for, and on what table.

Comment: What happens if he populates details before order

Comment: Assuming `order_id column is actually a foreign key between `order` and `order_details`, that would be impossible.

Comment: Not to sound pessimistic but assuming the code presented is standard, I doubt there are any foreign keys

Comment: @siggemannen Well, that's for the OP to know and the rest of us to guess....

Comment: So i must delate my first trigger and after that create only your version trigger on tabel ORDER_DETAILS ? Yes ?

Comment: Yes, you should delete your first trigger and create another one in `order_details` table.